# Automapper - Create Object if src not null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

sHow can I do something like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Ad, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ask_Id == null ? null : new Ask { Id = src.Ask_Id }))
```

I get an unsupported mapping error.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post class structures also.

Comment: Hi, Sorry but when I checked again, I found an error in the mapping, it's dest => dest.Ask, and not dest => dest.Ad. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how your class object looks like, Pre-assuming that you have classes like below,

```
class Ask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class DestinationDto
{
    public Ask Ad { get; set; }
}

class SourceDto
{
    public int? Ask_Id { get; set; }
}
```

If so, then use below mapper.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDto, DestinationDto>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Ad, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ask_Id == null ? null : new Ask { Id = src.Ask_Id.Value }));

var source = new SourceDto { Ask_Id = 1}; // try with null
var destination = Mapper.Map<SourceDto, DestinationDto>(source);
```

Comment: Hi, I get "Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"